# DAX Calcuate rolling sum

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem with calculating measure that sums values for 3 previous periods.
Below I attach sample fact table and dict table to show problem I am facing.

| date | customer | segment | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 | 1 | A | 10 |
| 02.01.2021 | 1 | A | 10 |
| 03.01.2021 | 1 | A | 10 |
| 04.01.2021 | 1 | A | 10 |
| 01.01.2021 | 2 | B | 20 |
| 02.01.2021 | 2 | B | 30 |
| 03.01.2021 | 2 | B | 40 |

dict table:

| segment | segment_desc |
| --- | --- |
| A | Name of A |
| B | Name of B |

Approach I have taken:

```
last 3 value = 
VAR DATES = DATESINPERIOD(facts[date],LASTDATE(facts[date]), -3,MONTH)
RETURN CALCULATE([sum value], DATES)
```

It produces correct results as long as there is at least one record for April.
When I use filter on segment_desc = 'B'
It produces result as I attached - so we see result in April equals 20, which is obviously not what I wanted. I would expect it to be 50.

[image]

Comment: you need to add a proper calendar table to your data model, and use dates from it, not from the fact table.

Comment: You have saved my day, now it works like a charm. Could you give me a hint why previously it showed value for January?

Comment: I posted an answer with the explanation to your last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the main question:
time intelligence functions like DATESINPERIOD require a proper calendar table, because they expect continuous dates, without gaps.

Answer to the follow-up question "why the measure shows value for January?"

It's a bit tricky. First, notice that LASTDATE in this filter context returns blank:

[image]

So, your DAX measure then becomes this:

```
last 3 value = 
VAR DATES = DATESINPERIOD(facts[date], BLANK(), -3,MONTH)
RETURN CALCULATE([sum value], DATES)
```

Blank - 3 month does not make sense, so the way DAX resolves this: it replaces BLANK with the first (min) date in the table. In this case, it's 1/1/2021. Then it goes back 3 months from that date. As a result, the final measure is:

```
last 3 value = 
CALCULATE([sum value], {2020-11-01, 2020-12-01, 2021-01-01 })
```

Since you have no data prior to 2021-01-01, the final result shows only January values.